# Why dont I see folder containing the minified files in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) to bundle and minify JS and CSS files in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Most of the suggestions are already available out of the box.

This is how my code looks:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundleOne").Include(
                "~/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
                 "~/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                 "~/js/bootstrap-suggest.js",
                 "~/js/Internal.js",
                 "~/js/abc.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundleTwo").Include(
                "~/js/common.js"));
}
```

This is how global.asax file looks:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

I am building application with debug mode set to false.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
```

and using following syntax to reference the bundle

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundleOne")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundleTwo")
```

**While all this is working fine, I do not see folder named bundles which contains the minified file. The behavior is same when I publish the solution.**

Comment: You do not see a folder containing minified resources as this process takes place at runtime. It basically works out from the request what type of browser it is making the request and only then bundle, minify if the app is running in non debug mode.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey: Is there any way to generate files physically ? When I run the application locally on visual studio, my application works fine but when I deploy it after publishing the code using visual studio, I am seeing `myApp:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function` error

Comment: please make sure that the order of your scripts defined in bundle is correct and all your third party libraries are actually included. tooltip is not a function basically means maybe the module/library is not  loaded and js engine has no idea about any function named as tooltip that you may want to execute on a jquery object.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey :I am pretty sure that I added the files & required files in correct order & I am not getting this error locally. It comes only when I publish.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the debug mode of your application. If I am not mistaken, in debug mode there is no minification.

Comment: I am already doing this in my web.config file: `<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>`